# Android Studio -- Cannot resolve symbol 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working in Android Studios when it crashed. Upon restarting I received the following error for each import:

***Cannot resolve symbol 'android'***

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
...
```

I've tried:

1. Invalidate and restart cache
2. Cloning my repository and importing the project
3. Restarting Android Studio
4. Updating Android Studio to version 3.0

Comment: Can you share your gradle content, including your dependencies?

Comment: @Fio Actually got it to work by uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall Android Studio. Reset local repo to match (working) remote repo